# How can I create an instance of a custom model with multiple viewcontrollers in Xcode with Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, model, xcode9

I'm new to Swift and I'm sure this question is pretty basic and has been asked and answered before.

I am not using `storyBoard`. My main `viewController` is created from `AppDelegate` via code.

I have:

- a custom class defined in a model.swift file
- a main `viewController` (from `AppDelegate`) that I am using as a container
- 3 additional viewcontrollers as subviews of the main (not each other)
- all 3 subviews are displayed simultaneously each covering 1/3 of the screen (no segues)
- each viewcontroller is in a separate .swift file

**I want to create an instance of my custom class in the main `viewController` and have all 3 of the subviews be able to reference that instance.**

Each of the subview view controllers need to be able to get/set instance variables and the other subviews need to be made aware of those changes.

I think I will need to use notifications to communicate the changes to the multiple subviews - but I haven't even begun to try and figure that out yet.

If this *has* been asked and answered before - could someone please either provide a link - or provide me with the right search terms so that I'm able to find the answer?  The only found answers I've found that come close are to use segues to pass the data back and forth.

Comment: Hi Jim, why do you definitely need a view controller for the subviews in your main view? I think you're making it yourself pretty difficult. One view controller managing the main view and three subviews added to that main view.

Comment: Here's how I would do it. Create a singleton class. Configure the singleton's properties in the the main ViewController. Use `didSet` to post a Notification and then add a listener for that notification in your additional ViewControllers.

Comment: Bad Practice: keeping three separate view controllers inside a view controller for just managing three views. Is there any reason for doing this?

Comment: @MacUser/@Mani - I don’t know that I do “definitely” need ViewControllers for all 3 SubViews.  My first attempt was worse and I was actually creating 3 Windows - each 1/3 of the screen height.  The uppermost View and bottommost View are UICollectionViews each with a flowLayout.  The middle View is just a normal panel that I intend to swap in and out with 2 or 3 alternate panels depending on the phase of the app.  I don’t know how I would be able to put 2 CollectionViews inside the same ViewController?

Comment: So - I’m open to alternate ideas - but I think there must be a way to do this and I think it would be good to know how.  To add more context, let’s say that my class is named “GameData”.  It has 7 or 8 vars that contain either String or [Int] data and methods to “ResetGame”, “DrawCard”, “ShuffleDeck”, “P1Cards” and “P2Cards”.  I want my Main ViewController to create and manage an instance of GameData - then I want all 3 subViews to have their own “live” reference to it, put a “deal” button in the middle controller and have the top/bottom views see that the p1cards and p2cards have changed.

Comment: @Sam - Thank you.  The Singleton was the answer I was looking for.  I had seen articles that stated using Singletons was not a great practice so I had never actually looked up exactly what they were.  After you posted your comment, I googled them and it turns out that they were exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So - this was my first question on StackOverflow - and I have my main answer now.  What is the right way for me to close off this question?

Comment: @Jim I have posted my comment as an answer. Since it seemed to help you, you can choose to accept it and that'll mark your question as solved. Also, welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Create a singleton class.
2. Configure the singleton's properties in the the main ViewController.
3. Use didSet to post a Notification.
4. Add a listener for that Notification in your additional ViewControllers.

Comment: Thank you!  The Singleton was what I needed!  But - and tell me if this is stupid.  The way I handled the refreshes is by adding a function to each ViewController called “refreshGameData()”.  I added 3 properties to my custom object (1 for each ViewController) and stored a reference to each ViewController in a separate property.  So when I modify data from one of the View controllers and need to refresh the others - I can call GameData.ViewController#.refreshGameData() for the ones I need to refresh.  It’s tested and working - so unless this is really, really REALLY stupid - I think I’m done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegate pattern. Below code is assuming that you are using `MVVM` pattern. (It is very similar for `VIPER`/`ReSwift` patterns also)

```
protocol DataChangedDelegate {
  func refreshData()
}

// ViewModel for FirstViewController
class FirstViewModel {
   var delegate: DataChangedDelegate?

   var data: Any {
     didSet {
       delegate?.refreshData()
     }
  }
  //rest of the things
}

//similarly other two view models will have a delegate and on data change will call the refresh method
```

And your view controllers should adopt this protocol

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DataChangedDelegate {
  //view controller code

  //delegate code
  func refreshDate() {
    //tableView.reloadDate()
    //collectionView.reloadDate()
    //lableView.text = viewModel.data()
  }
}
```

And where ever you create a viewControllers and add as subView, you have to set the delegate of viewModel.

```
let firstViewController: FirstViewController = createFirstViewController()
let firstViewModel = FirstViewModel()
firstViewModel.delegate = firstViewController
firstViewController.viewModel = firstViewModel
mainViewController.addSubView(firstViewController.view)
```

Similarly for all other view controllers.

Comment: This seems to answer the “next” question that I eluded to in my original post - how to let all the controllers know when to refresh their data - so thank you - but the question I was asking was how to get them all to SEE the data initially.

Comment: You will create your 3 view controllers either in MainViewController (didLoad) or in AppDelegate. Create one custom class instance and assign it to each VC. Then add this ViewControllers as subviews of Main ViewController. Hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: Nope.  That’s the part I already have working.  The part I was missing was how to create and use a Singleton class so that my data object was available globally - to all of the ViewControllers.  So now I’ve got that working also.  Thank you for your replies though. Now I’m at the point where I need to implement the delegate pattern from your first reply.

Comment: Happy that my part of answer help you. In my previous comment, I mention **Create one class instance and assign to all VC*** which is basically singleton.. Anyway you got it working. Cool

Comment: Right - you did say “Create one class instance and assign to all VC” which basically just restated the question I was asking.  I knew that I needed/wanted to do that - but I didn’t know *HOW* to do it...or that it was called a Singleton.  Sam used the magic word “Singleton” which gave me what I needed in order to find a “how to” with Google.  I do appreciate your responses though - so Thank You for your help!  I just wanted to explain why your first answer didn’t help me more.